# Why do I get a black screen when I increase the font size and how do I fix it? kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

By pressing the two buttons I display the information (text) obtained from the site. But when I try to increase the font size of this text, I get a black screen at all values above a certain one.
For example at a size of 35 I still display the text, but at 40 it is already a black screen

python script:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import requests

Builder.load_string('''

# Define the scroll view
<ScrollableLabel>:
    Label:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (.93, .91, .67, 1)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        padding: (10,10)
        id: label
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        font_size: 35
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
<MyGridLayout>:
    spacing: 30
    size_hint_y: None
    size: self.width, 200
    padding: (10,0,10,10)
<NextButton>:
    text: 'Следующая стр...'
    font_size: self.width / 9
    size_hint: 0.02,1
    background_color: (.93, .91, .67, 1)
    background_normal: ''
    color: (0,0,0,1)

<PreviousButton>:
    text: 'Предыдущая стр...'
    font_size: self.width / 9
    size_hint: 0.02,1
    background_color: (.93, .91, .67, 1)
    background_normal: ''
    color: (0,0,0,1)
<MyLabel>:
    size_hint: 0.01,0.01

''')

x = 1


class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    pass


class NextButton(Button):
    pass


class PreviousButton(Button):
    pass


class MyLabel(Label):
    pass


class MyButton(Button):
    color = (0, 0, 0, 1)
    valign = 'bottom'
    padding_y = 10
    background_color = (.93, .91, .67, 1)
    background_normal = ''
    font_size = 35


class ScrollableLabel(ScrollView):
    pass


class Box(BoxLayout):
    color = (.98, .98, .82, 1)
    orientation = "vertical"
    spacing = 10

    def on_kv_post(self, widget):
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='4 класс', on_press=self.btn_menu))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='5 класс', on_press=self.btn_menu))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='6 класс', on_press=self.btn_menu))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='7 класс', on_press=self.btn_menu))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='8 класс', on_press=self.btn_menu))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='9 класс', on_press=self.btn_menu))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='10 класс', on_press=self.btn_menu))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='11 класс', on_press=self.btn_menu))

    def btn_menu(self, widget):
        self.clear_widgets()
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='И. С. Тургенев. Отцы и дети', on_press=self.btn_press))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='И. А. Гончаров. Обломов.', on_press=self.btn_press))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='Ф. М. Достоевский. Преступление и наказание.', on_press=self.btn_press))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='Л. Н. Толстой. Война и мир.', on_press=self.btn_press))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='Н. С. Лесков. Очарованный странник. ', on_press=self.btn_press))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='Н. А. Некрасов. Лирика. Кому на Руси жить хорошо...', on_press=self.btn_press))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='А. И. Островский. Гроза.', on_press=self.btn_press))
        self.add_widget(MyButton(text='А. П. Чехов. Вишневый сад.', on_press=self.btn_press))

    def btn_press(self, instance):
        self.clear_widgets()
        sc = ScrollableLabel()
        global x
        data = ''
        url = "http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=12021&p=1"
        request = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
        teme = soup.find_all("p", class_="MsoNormal")
        for temes in teme:
            data += temes.text
        sc.ids.label.text = data

        self.add_widget(sc)
        gd = MyGridLayout(cols=3)
        gd.add_widget(PreviousButton(on_press=self.previous_page))
        gd.add_widget(MyLabel(text=f'стр № {x}', color=(1, 1, 1, 1)))
        gd.add_widget(NextButton(on_press=self.next_page))

        self.add_widget(gd)

    def next_page(self, instance):
        self.clear_widgets()
        sc = ScrollableLabel()
        data = ''
        global x
        x += 1
        url = "http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=12021&p=" + f'{x}'
        request = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
        teme = soup.find_all("p", class_="MsoNormal")
        for temes in teme:
            data += temes.text
        sc.ids.label.text = data
        self.add_widget(sc)
        gd = MyGridLayout(cols=3)
        gd.add_widget(PreviousButton(on_press=self.previous_page))
        gd.add_widget(MyLabel(text=f'стр № {x}'))
        gd.add_widget(NextButton(on_press=self.next_page))

        self.add_widget(gd)

    def previous_page(self, instance):
        self.clear_widgets()
        sc = ScrollableLabel()
        data = ''
        global x
        if x != 1:
            x -= 1
        url = "http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=12021&p=" + f'{x}'
        request = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
        teme = soup.find_all("p", class_="MsoNormal")
        for temes in teme:
            data += temes.text
        sc.ids.label.text = data
        self.add_widget(sc)
        gd = MyGridLayout(cols=3)
        gd.add_widget(PreviousButton(on_press=self.previous_page))
        gd.add_widget(MyLabel(text=f'стр № {x}'))
        gd.add_widget(NextButton(on_press=self.next_page))

        self.add_widget(gd)


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Box()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

How can i fix it?

The label and text, which i need are in this part of the code

```
 <ScrollableLabel>:
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: (.93, .91, .67, 1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            padding: (10,10)
            id: label
            color: (0,0,0,1)
            font_size: 35
            text_size: self.width, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Label` is exceeding the max allowed `Texture` size. You can access the max allowed size as:

```
from kivy.graphics.opengl import glGetIntegerv, GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE
max_texture_size = glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)[0]
```

I suggest using a `BoxLayout` in your `ScrollableLabel` and put a series of `Labels` in the `BoxLayout` instead of just one huge `Label`. Or perhaps replace the `ScrollableLabel` with a `TextInput` with `readonly: True`.

Comment: Ye, thank u :) 
I am just put my TextInput in ScrollableLabel and it works. Only one problem is on phone now is connected with a selection) When i selected smth on textinput, i cant cancel it or do smth about it. May be i can just disable selection? Didnt find anyth about this in docs)